# Angular UI View - Old and New views showing while view change in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-ui-router

I have AngularJS application, which uses UI router. In chrome the application is working fine, but not in Firefox.

The problem is when a state is changed, the DOM will have 2 `ui-views`. One for old and one for new. In chrome it will show only one view at a time, but in Firefox it is showing both views at a time for fraction of seconds.
The old view goes down and new one comes top. I'm not using ng-animate for view change. Even if I use, it's still showing both at a time.
I tried using `ng-cloak`, but it's not working.

```
<div ng-cloak>
            <div ui-view="mainview"></div>
        </div>
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing ngAnimate completely from my app.module dependencies. This is temporary since I would like to use ngAnimate, but it seems that the very presence of the module caused the double ui-view bug.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ng-animate did solve this for me as well. I had the issue in Chrome as well though.